How can I use a Python dictionary to update values in a Postgres SQL database more efficiently?
I have a python dictionary:
id_to_contract_date = {1: 20242222, 2:20240303, 3:20240404, 102834: 20240505, ...}

My SQL table looks like this:
   id       fid             ts                  val
    1       900     2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   Futures
    1       4055    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   202406
    1       4057    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   202406
    3       900     2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   Stock
    3       4055    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   202302
    3       4057    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   202302
   ...
  

i.e. every id has 3 different fids, as in the example above.
What I would like to do is replace the val for fid=4055 and 4057 for each id with the value in my dictionary.
So in the above example, the desired output is:
   id       fid             ts                  val
    1       900     2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   Futures
    1       4055    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   20242222
    1       4057    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   20242222
    3       900     2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   Stock
    3       4055    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   20240404
    3       4057    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   20240404
   ...

I have written some python code to achieve this:
for contract_id in id_to_contract_date_map:
    contract_ids_contract_date = id_to_contract_date_map[contract_id]
    
    sql = SQL(format_triple_quoted_string("""
                update sval set val = {contract_ids_contract_date} where fid in (4055, 4057) 
                and id = {contract_id};
                """)).format(contract_id=Literal(contract_id),
                             contract_ids_contract_date=Literal(contract_ids_contract_date))

    session.execute(sql_to_string(session, sql))

I believe the above works - yet to test it, but it seems terribly inefficient to connect to the database for each contract_id
Is there a better way to achieve the above?
Any help would be must appreciated! :)


Use psycopg2 directly with sql . 2) Use Fast execution helpers execute_batch() or execute_values().


parameterized sql will make repeated parsing of the statement unnecessary

Create a temp table (or cte) with those keys and values. Then you can do this in one statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql-server

.execute_values(), passing an iterator over your payload and adjusting page_size. Here's a demonstration of that, with benchmarks, details, and some additional tricks. Asyncpg copy_records_to_table might also be a good pick.
